# Missing Ruby/Rails Options When Installing Aptana Studio

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, eclipse, aptana

I've tried installing both the Aptana plugin (I'm running Juno) and Aptana studio itself from http://www.aptana.com/products/studio3/download.

Just like with my previous experience with PyDev, I learned that I had to point Eclipse to my Ruby interpreter, but when I open my **window > preferences** dialog, there are no options for Ruby like what I've seen from tutorials and whatnot:

[image: Eclipse dialog missing ruby options]

Even though Eclipse will allow me to create a new project, I don't see any option to create a Ruby source file:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aptana studio now works fine for Rails projects for some reason. The only explanation I can come up with is that the particular version of Aptana Studio I was using was giving me issues.

Answer (score 0):

You can just create a simple file and put the .rb extension in it and all should work. Regarding the ruby configurations, I believe it expects ruby to be found in your PATH.